# Django ManyToManyField with many same IDs

Tags: sql, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make a simple pizza order app in Django. I have 3 models (Toppings, Pizzas, Orders). In Orders model have ManyToManyField to Pizza. It's working fine if "user" orders one each pizza (Margarita and Pepperoni for example) but if order 2 Margarita in POST request I got only one Margarita ID in my result. How i can pass n-pizzas in one Order?

My models looks like this:

```
class Toppings(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, unique=True)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Toppings, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza, blank=False, null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[
        (1, 'placed'),
        (2, 'approved'),
        (3, 'cooked'),
        (4, 'delivered'),
        (5, 'canceled')
    ], default=1)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.created
```

I send POST with this data:

```
{
    "items": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    "status": 1
}
```

and got this only 1 and 2 in items list (not 1,1,1,2,2):

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "items": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "status": 1
}
```

Serializer and view for Order

```
class OrdersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        fields = ['id', 'items', 'status', 'created']


class PizzaOrdersList(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PizzaOrder.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrdersSerializer
```

Comment: Because items are referencing to pizza model. So 1 Order A reference to Pizza1 a 1000 times then it still 1 Oder A reference to 1 Pizza1. I think you'll need to create a PizzaOrderItem which has a reference to Pizza and the amount of that kind of pizza

Comment: Can you show the example of PizzaOrderItem model and how to count items from Oder post request?

Comment: below answer already answered your question.. that's a good answer

Answer (score 5):

A through model is perfect for this. `ManyToManyFields` create this kind of database relationship in the background, which only creates unique combinations of Pizza and PizzaOrder, but you can easily implement it yourself.

Simply create a class called `PizzaOrderItem`, which contains the `ForeignKeys` to both Pizza and PizzaOrder models:

```
class PizzaOrderItem(models.Model):
    pizza = ForeignKey(Pizza)
    pizza_order = ForeignKey(PizzaOrder)
```

You can then change the ManyToManyField to use your custom created through model:

```
class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    ...
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza, through='<your_app_name>.PizzaOrderItem',
        blank=False, 
        null=False)
    ...
```

You could even add extra fields to your through model like toppings or quantity, like this:

```
class PizzaOrderItem(models.Model):
        pizza = ForeignKey(Pizza)
        pizza_order = ForeignKey(PizzaOrder)

        toppings = ManyToManyField(Toppings)
        quantity = IntegerField(default=1)
```

You can access the pizzas in an order through `order.items` and the actual through model objects through `order.pizza_order_item_set`.

---

**Serializers**

Retrieving the items for an order is pretty simple.
To properly show your new `PizzaOrderItems`, you'll need to do add a serializer, and set items on `PizzaOrderSerializer` to use your new serializer:

```
class PizzaOrderItemSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrderItem
        # If you add a field like quantity you can add them to the fields list below.
        fields = ['pizza', 'pizza_order']


class PizzaOrderSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    items = PizzaOrderItemSerializer(source='pizza_order_item_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        fields = ['id', 'items', 'status', 'created']
```

---

**Creating PizzaOrderItems**

There are two ways to create PizzaOrderItems. The first one is pretty straightforward. Simply create a view similar to `PizzaOrder`, and use the `PizzaOrderItemSerializer`:

```
class PizzaOrderItemViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = PizzaOrderItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaOrderItemSerializer
```

You can then create items for an order using a POST data:

```
{
     "pizza" : <pizza_id_here>
     "pizza_order" : <pizza_order_id_here>
}
```

---

The second way is to only use the PizzaOrder view, and override the create functions to the PizzaOrder serializer. This is because a nested serializer is read-only by default, so what we do here is override the create method for the root serializer, and create sub-objects using the nested serializer's validated data.

```
class PizzaOrderSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        items = validated_data.pop('items')
        order = PizzaOrder.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for item_data in items:
            PizzaOrderItem.objects.create(pizza_order=order, **item_data)
        return order
```

If you use this method, you can create order with POST data this:

```
{
    "items": [
                  { "pizza" : 1 },
                  { "pizza" : 1 },
                  { "pizza" : 2 },
                  { "pizza" : 2 },
             ]
    "status": 1
}
```

Comment: Great answer! For reference, here is the related doc on this topic: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thank you so much! My order serializer class OrdersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        fields = ['id', 'items', 'status', 'created']

Comment: Can you help with serializers and views?

Comment: Yeah, I was away for a while. I've updated my answer

Comment: It's does not work actually. { "pizza_order": [ "Invalid pk \"1\" - object does not exist." ]} And what is AuthorsOrder ?

Comment: My bad, AuthorsOrder was a remnant of my own code. It should be PizzaOrderItem. Also, did you check that there is actually a pizza with id 1? It's an example, so it should be an exisiting pizza

Comment: Now it's better but one issue and i can't figure out why. Can you check my code - https://www.codepile.net/raw/ME7lnpkg.py and tell why i can get "pizza":null and id - ok https://yadi.sk/i/kP-qrb7lmbkPjw ?

Comment: Can you also share the POST request you send when creating a PizzaOrder?